# WebDriver URL Timeout doesn't seem to be working

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have the following code in my test class (java) but the timeout doesn't seem to work (it has no effect at all). I've tested it with really slow connections and I expect it to fail after 5 secnods but it waits for page to load indefinately and sometimes it come back in 8-10 seconds and the test passes as the page has actually loaded but not within the time I specified. Any idea why page timeout command is not doing what it is supposed to do?

`protected static WebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");`

I'm using Selenium 2.20.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Then report it as an issue

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

pageLoadTimeOut makes no sense without "unstable" Firefox profile.

Probably, you will have to either download the plugin been mentioned at the selenium download page OR write a while loop that would run indefinitely and break only when the element is found. Make use of try-catch blocks as well.